# Visualize the model's training process taking into account ModelCheckpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a Tensorflow model, in which I include a checkpoint to save the best model (based on val_loss).

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_rmse', verbose=2, \
                             save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, \
                             mode='min', save_frequency=1)
```

After the training, to visualize the model's training process epoch after epoch using the stats stored in the r objects. I do:

```
plotter.plot({'Basic': history}, metric = 'loss')
```

Question: How do I do if I want to visual the model's straining process not epoch after epoch but only until the best model is saved. E.gg, if I initially set epoch=5,000 but the best model is at epoch = 2,000, I want to chart only until epoch = 2,000.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/): The `filepath` can contain named formatting options, which will be filled with the values of `epoch` and keys in `logs` (passed in on_epoch_end).

For example: if `filepath` is weights.{`epoch`:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5, then the model checkpoints will be saved with the `epoch` number and the validation loss in the filename. e.g **weights.0150-0.88.hdf5**

You can then inspect the file name and plot until the desired epoch number.

Comment: In the same vein, if the epoch=400 is an outlier (let say, the val_loss spikes), is there a way to remove this from the chart and takes into account only the epochs for which the val_loss actually decreases?

Comment: If you want to tamper with the loss values just for plotting I think you can begin with:


1. Using an algorithm of spline or exponential moving average (EMA, used in the tensorboard plots e.g.).  This will not remove the point but will make it less evident on the curve.

Comment: 2. To completely remove from the chart you can check a point and the subsequent and only plot  when the latter is between a predefined range of variation (trying to detect the spike here). 
If outside the range is up to you to decide what to place in this spot, maybe the exactly value of the previous sample, maybe the average of the previous 5 samples, maybe skip and use the next 'good' sample, etc.